# Codecov integration with circleci

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, circleci, circleci-2.0

I want to integrate codecov with circleci.
My config.yml file is  like:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@0.1.2 
  codecov: codecov/codecov@1.0.2


jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.3-stretch-node
    executor: ruby/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Force Bundler Version
          command: |
            sudo gem update --system
            echo 'export BUNDLER_VERSION=$(cat Gemfile.lock | tail -1 | tr -d " ")' >> $BASH_ENV
            source $BASH_ENV
            gem install bundler
    steps:
      - codecov/upload:
          file: {{ coverage_report_filepath }}
```

**I am getting build error on CIRCLECI**

*Unable to parse YAML found duplicate key steps in 'string', line 21, column 5: steps*

Comment: I have tried removing **duplications** but same results, can any one **help**

Comment: How it could be the same result if you remove `steps:` from line 21?

Comment: @Yakov can we do everything in one job ?

Comment: i folloed this link....
(https://circleci.com/blog/making-code-coverage-easy-to-see-with-the-codecov-orb/)

Comment: I believe it should be done in one job and under one `steps` directive.

Comment: @Yakov can't we have  multiple jobs in one orb ?

Comment: What do you mean? Speaking in the context of the error. Have you tried to remove duplicated key `steps`?

Comment: @Yakov it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `steps` defined twice for the same job.

If you want the `codecov/upload` command to be part of the build job then you would just add it in

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.3-stretch-node
    executor: ruby/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Force Bundler Version
          command: |
            sudo gem update --system
            echo 'export BUNDLER_VERSION=$(cat Gemfile.lock | tail -1 | tr -d " ")' >> $BASH_ENV
            source $BASH_ENV
            gem install bundler
      - codecov/upload:
          file: {{ coverage_report_filepath }}
```